# Difference between join() and complete()

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Given a CompletableJob, what is the difference between `job.join()` and `job.complete()`? From the documentation, I understand that `job.join()` suspends the current thread until that job is completed. Isn't that the same as `job.complete()`? It seems to me that it also waits until the job is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are entirely different operations: `join()` waits for the job to complete (but doesn't make it complete), `complete()` completes the job, but doesn't wait on anything.

From your description I feel like you read the documentation for `join()`, but you didn't read the docs for [complete()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-completable-job/complete.html), as it does entirely different thing than you assume:

> Completes this job. The result is true if this job was completed as a result of this invocation and false otherwise (if it was already completed). (...) This function transitions this job into completed state if it was not completed or cancelled yet.

Comment: Thanks, I've read the quoted documentation but what I don't understand is, how can a job be completed without waiting for it to reach completion?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Why do we have to wait in order to set something? `CompletableJob` is like a mutable property. We can set its value (`complete()`), we can read its value (`isCompleted`), we can also wait until it's completed (`join()`). Why setting a value would mean we wait for it to be set?

Comment: Thanks, I had misunderstood the usage of CompletableJob. I imagined it just like a Job that you get when you call `launch`, but additionally it's completable. So this CompletableJob is more like a mutable class whose "completed" property you can change at will? Wouldn't that put the job into a state where it's lying, i.e. it says it's completed but the coroutine that it represents is in fact still running?

Comment: Yes, `CompletableJob` is merely an observable variable. Please someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe `CoopletableJob` can't be implicitly associated with some real work that we started. There is no function like `launch {}`, but returning a `CompletableJob`. Use cases for this util are situations where we need to explicitly set its status, there are no coroutines behind it.

Comment: What about the `Job` factory function that takes a `Job` parameter, as in  `coroutineScope { val j = Job(launch { do something time-consuming }); j.complete() }` - now `j` is "complete" but the actual job isn't.

Comment: Ohh, you confused yourself a lot with this code. There is no `Job()` "constructor" that accepts a work to do. If there would be, it would probably accept a lambda. This above code first launches the code (job1), then creates another Job (job2) and associates job2 as a child of job1. Please note `Job()` that you use accepts a param called `parent`.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Coroutines had never been my strong point.

Comment: One last thing: we could ask, what will happen if we add a child to the completable job - how is it possible we can complete that job then? Actually, docs for `complete()` answer that question. We complete only the parent job itself, but it still have to wait for its children. So I assume calling `complete()` doesn't necessarily mean `isComplete` will be immediately true.